# Why is no request made on retrofit call?

Tags: android, python, django-rest-framework, retrofit, multipartform-data

I want my android users to be able to upload a profile image to the django rest api. I use retrofit to handle the upload:

**UserService**

```
@Multipart
@POST("users/upload-profile-image/")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadProfileImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part image,
                                      @Part("name") RequestBody name);
```

**UserRepository**

```
RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", file.getName(), reqFile);
RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "upload");

Call<ResponseBody> req = userServiceApi.uploadProfileImage(body, name);
req.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call,
                           @NonNull Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        // Do Something
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Successfully uploaded image");
        } else {
            eventBus.post(new FailUploadProfileImageEvent());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

**To instantiate the** `userServiceAPI`

```
userServiceApi = ServiceGenerator.createService(UserService.class, token);
```

**ServiceGenerator**

```
// Actual digits replaced with X
private static final String BASE_API_URL = "http://XXX.XXX.X.XXX:8000/";

private static OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

private static Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_API_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, String token) {
    if (token != null)
        okHttpBuilder.authenticator(new TokenAuthenticator(token));

    OkHttpClient client = okHttpBuilder.build();
    builder.client(client);
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
```

**users/urls.py**

```
url(r'^upload-profile-image/$', views.UserProfileUploadImageView.as_view(), name="upload_profile_image"),
```

When I run the android app, no request is made to the server, why?

Comment: _When I run the android app, no request is made to the server, why?_ Are you calling the upload method right after launching your app?

Comment: Did you check your internet permission?

Comment: I have many other network requests that work fine and my internet permissions are correct. I am calling the upload method when a user clicks the change image button

Comment: So this method is not called upon launching my app